# Como remover todas as referencias dos formulários acestras deletadas do formulário pai?

Tags: delphi, herança, pascal, delphi-xe6

Tenho meu formulário genérico e tenho diversos outros que herdaram visualmente seus componentes. Quando deleto um componente no formulário *pai* e abro um *herdeiro* recebo essa mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Posso clicar em OK e confirmar que o componente foi deletado, porém terei que fazer isso em mais de 50 formulários.

Existe alguma forma de dar um clean em todos os outros formulários automaticamente? Teria um editor que poderia em lote substituir ou remover a expressão, como por exemplo:

```
inherited dxLayoutControl1Group2: TdxLayoutAutoCreatedGroup
  Index = 0
  AutoCreated = True
end
```

Comment: O que quer dizer com "herdam"?

Comment: @Guill herança é uma característica da POO, neste caso seria a herança visual da UI.

Comment: Exiba o código que está utilizando para criar os formulários herdeiros?

Comment: Vc diz criar em termos de objeto?Ou criar o formulário em si?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...
**EDIT**

Então amigo, acabei vendo usa edição e realmente o **NotePad++** não consegue fazer!

O que nos resta fazer? *Criei uma ferramenta para isso e vou compartilhar com a comunidade*! Não só isso, que resolva o problema e qualquer outro semelhante que possa aparecer com o mesmo sentido!

**Interface da Ferramenta (aproveitei e deixei os nomes dos componentes):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**btnListar**:

```
procedure TfrmRemoverReferencias.btnListarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mmListaArquivos.Lines.Clear;
  //Chamando a função que lista os Arquivos e Subpastas
  ListarArquivos(edtDiretorio.Text, chkSub.Checked);
end;
```

**Função para auxiliar na busca dos arquivos e identificação de pastas vazias:**

```
function TfrmRemoverReferencias.TemAtributo(Attr, Val: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Attr and Val = Val;
end;
```

**Função que vai buscar os arquivos da Pasta informada em `edtDiretorio` observe que adicionei o `edtExtensao` para que possa escolher que tipo será exclusivamente listado, ainda temos o `chkSub` um adicional que podemos usar para buscar as subpastas (um brilho a mais para nossa ferramenta):**

```
procedure TfrmRemoverReferencias.ListarArquivos(Diretorio: string; Sub: Boolean);
var
  F: TSearchRec;
  Ret: Integer;
  TempNome: string;
begin
  Ret := FindFirst(Diretorio + '\*.'+edtExtensao.Text, faAnyFile, F);
  while Ret = 0 do
  begin
    if TemAtributo(F.Attr, faDirectory) then
    begin
      if (F.Name <> '.')  and
         (F.Name <> '..') then
      begin
        if Sub = True then
        begin
          TempNome := Diretorio + '\' + F.Name;
          ListarArquivos(TempNome, True);
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      mmListaArquivos.Lines.Add(Diretorio + '\' + F.Name);
    end;
    Ret := FindNext(F);
  end;
  FindClose(F);
end;
```

**Agora, no btnCorrigir:**

```
procedure TfrmRemoverReferencias.btnCorrigirClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,
  x,
  y,
  z,
  w,
  vIndex,
  vTamLoop,
  vNLinhas     : Integer;
  vDados       : Array of String;
  vArquivoTemp : TStringList;

begin
  vArquivoTemp := TStringList.Create;
  vArquivoTemp.Clear;
  vIndex       := 0;
  SetLength(vDados, mmFonteDados.Lines.Count);

  for i := 0 to Pred(mmFonteDados.Lines.Count) do
    vDados[i] := mmFonteDados.Lines.Strings[i];

  {Para cada arquivo da Lista...}
  for i := 0 to Pred(mmListaArquivos.Lines.Count) do
  begin
    vArquivoTemp.LoadFromFile(mmListaArquivos.Lines.Strings[i]);
    vTamLoop := vArquivoTemp.Count;

    for x := 0 to Pred(vTamLoop) do
    begin
      if (x >= vTamLoop) then
        Break;
      {... para cada linha da Fonte de pesquisa}
      for y := 0 to Pred(mmFonteDados.Lines.Count) do
      begin

        for z := 0 to Pred(mmFonteDados.Lines.Count) do
        begin
          if (x + z >= vTamLoop) then
            Break;

          {... se encontrei a 1ª ocorreência...}
          if (Pos(vDados[0+z],vArquivoTemp.Strings[x+z]) > 0) then
            Inc(vIndex)
          else
            vIndex := 0;
        end;

        {Testando se achei todas as ocorrências}
        if (vIndex = mmFonteDados.Lines.Count) then
        begin
          for w :=  0 to Pred(vIndex) do
          begin
            {Deletando a Linha qie Foi encontrada 4 vezes...
            ...sim, para esse exemplo vamos deletar 4 linhas...
            ... faça as implementações necessarias caso queira deletar mais que 4 linhas!
            NOTA, lembrando que a qtd de linhas são da variavel vIndex}
            vArquivoTemp.Delete(x);
          end;
          vTamLoop := vTamLoop - vIndex;
          vIndex := 0;
          {Salvando as Alterações}
          vArquivoTemp.SaveToFile(mmListaArquivos.Lines.Strings[i]);
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Fica a critério de cada um usar como bem entender, observem o :

```
for w := 0 to Pred(vIndex)
```

Aqui adicionei a função interna do Delphi  `Delete`, ou seja, vou apagar a linha inteira, caso for de sua escolha, basta substituir ela por um procedimento que adicione para aquela linha `//` e você estaria comentando a linha ao invés de apagar, ou dar um `StringReplace` para trocar de informação!

Nessa linha: `vArquivoTemp.SaveToFile(mmListaArquivos.Lines.Strings[i]);`aqui salvamos sob o arquivo original, para gerar uma copia basta alterar o `[i]` para `[i]+'corrigido'`.

Dava pra ter feito sem tantos laços? Sim, mas ficaria muito extenso!
Vou seguir melhorando ela com passar do tempo! Inclusive um colega de trabalho já vai usar!

Observe que não adicionei nenhuma validação de Campos, agora basta usar a imaginação!

Espero que ajude!

Comment: mas como eu dou um replace em algo como um component tipo `inherited dxLayoutControl1Group2: TdxLayoutAutoCreatedGroup
      Index = 0
      AutoCreated = True
    end`, ou seja tem que ser exatamente esta expressão

Comment: @Artur_Indio então... O editor de texto mencionado procura e encontra essa expressão facilmente.

Comment: Ele funciona da mesma forma do Notepad comum, não consigo substituir uma expressão de um componente, veja minha edição por favor.

Comment: @Artur_Indio Então amigo, segue edição da resposta, vamos aos testes!

Comment: Vou olhar e dou uma resposta, Vlw mesmo ai.