# Existe como mudar o tipo de campo de uma query no delphi sem ter que excluir e incluir?

Tags: delphi, postgresql, query, tipagem, zeos

Tenho a seguinte situação, uso o PostgreSQL e Zeos no DelphiXE, precisei atualizar o componente para suportar melhor o LATIN1 x UTF-8, agora consigo trabalhar com todo tipo de caractere, blz.

Mas surgiu outro problema, alguns campos que eram tipo Memo a nova versão do componente trata como String então o delphi "grita" na conversão.

A solução é simples, basta excluir o campo do DataSet e incluir novamente e ele pega o novo tipo, mas minha aplicação tem quase 400 formulários, imagine abrir um por um e ficar verificando os componentes.

Eu tenho o GExperts instalado que dá muitas opções de tratamento no projeto, mas não encontrei se ele faz essa troca de tipo em Fields.

Olhando nos Fields que o delphi reclama, eles estão como TStringField, mas quando tento abrir a query ele da a mensagem:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
zqrClientes: Type mismatch for field 'end_cid', expecting: String actual: Memo.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Se ele já está como TStringField, então não deveria gritar, mas sabe como é né... coisas so além acontecem, então fui lá no código do Form pra ver como está, ele está assim:

```
object zqrClientesend_cid: TStringField
      DisplayWidth = 255
      FieldName = 'end_cid'
      ReadOnly = True
      Size = 255
    end
```

O problema parece ser o tamanho do campo, que na base é 40 e no componente é 255, mas mudando somente o tamanho do campo não adianta.

Esse campo era um varchar sem especificação de tamanho no Postgres (erro na criação do campo), no componente antigo funcionava normal mesmo depois de mudar o tamanho para 40 caracter, mas agora mudando a versão do componente Zeos, ele grita.

Onde o delphi guarda a informação de que o componente é Memo e não String?

Já exclui as DUCs e recompilei e nada.

Em resumo a pergunta é:

Como trocar os tipos dos Fields da Querys no Delphi sem precisar excluir e incluir novamente, pois essa ação também quebra muitos links dos componentes relacionados aos Fields que serão excluídos.

Answer (score 1):

Precisei fazer isto a pouco tempo, lembre-se, existe `.pas` e `.dfm` um deles não esta como deveria.

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108221/como-remover-todas-as-referencias-dos-formul%C3%A1rios-acestras-deletadas-do-formul%C3%A1r) desenvolvi junto a outro usuário do SoPt uma solução parecida.

"A ideia é simples", procurar uma ocorrência e substituir.
Um detalhe é que existira um padrão.

```
object zqrClientesend_cid: TStringField
      DisplayWidth = 255
      FieldName = 'end_cid'
      ReadOnly = True
      Size = 255
    end
```

Basta utilizar o exemplo da resposta que linkei e procurar isto e trocar pelo que deseja!

Um, detalhe na sua pergunta é que diz ser simples, bastando excluir os campos e adiciona-los novamente, mas cuidado com o link dos eventos...

Comment: É eu citei os links, excluir desliga um monte de componente

Comment: Exatamente, e `Type mismatch for field 'end_cid', expecting: String actual: Memo.` era exatamente o meu problema o que difere são os tipos, troquei de `Float` para `Extended`, resolvi com link que passei na resposta!

Comment: Sabe uma coisa interessante Junior, o campo no delphi já esta como String, e ele diz que esta como Memo, veja no trecho do Form que voce copiou

Comment: Junior achei o problema aqui, um programador criou uma função no postgres que retorna character varying, o postgres permite vc criar um campo varchar sem especificar o tamanho, o correto seria character varying(tamanho), eu considero isso um bug, mas quem sou eu pra dizer isso, rs, mudei a função pra retornar text, e o delphi conseguiu compreender o tipo memo e não dá mais erro. Olha, perdi um tempão pra descobrir isso, :( agora estou fazendo uma varredura na base pra ver se existem mais campos ou funções criados desta forma.